# Spotipy can't see a previously set environment variable

Tags: python, environment-variables, spotipy

Whenever i'm trying to run a code using spotipy package an error "No client_id. Pass it or set a SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID environment variable." appears. I've set this variable to desired value and can call it using an echo function. I've tried to set it using an administrator command prompt and nothing changed.

I've set the variable using a self standing cmd, as well as in PyCharm, same results. When i run my program "No client id" error pops up but when i call echo function right after that i can see that the variable is set. I've tried passing it in powershell using $env:SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID="XXXX", but still nothing.

Comment: is your environment variable `SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID` or `SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID`?

Comment: You have to set them trough System Properties. Just search for *Variables*, and one result will pop up. Click that, and press the bottom button. There, you can set the variables.

Comment: Variable is SPOTIPY (as says the error). I've set it through system properties and it worked, thanks! Any idea why i couldn't do it with command prompt? Every tutorial about spotipy uses cmd and they don't seem to run into any issues